# ATI R9 270X 2GB and 3 high resolution monitors on Linux

Tags: linux, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon

I have three [ACHIEVA SHIMIAN QH270 27" LED 2560x1440](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Used-Refurbished-ACHIEVA-SHIMIAN-QH270-27-LED-2560x1440-QHD-S-IPS-PC-Monitor-/141482855003?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item20f1090a5b) monitors which I want to connect to a [Sapphire Radeon R9 270 2GB](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00I0D81OG).

Will this Card be able to handle three monitors at a total resolution of **7680x1440** in Linux and Windows?

The first two monitors will connect through the dual DVI connectors on the graphics card.
The third monitor will use a active display port to dual DVI convertor.

Also, I don't plan on using this setup to play games. Just use it as a development machine for programming.

Comment: This entirely depends on the connectors more then likely.

Comment: If you plan on playing games, then you can fully expect to lower a lot of settings to medium or lower in newer titles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no problem in connecting of three modest displays to this top-notch graphics card. Microsoft Surface Pro 3 can drive three external displays of up to 3200x2000 each, and it is even have no graphics card at all.

Your AMD R9 270X card will drive up to **6**. Here are tech specs: http://www.amd.com/en-us/products/graphics/desktop/r9#

Comment: Something to take note of is that the three monitors only have Dual DVI connectors. Would that be an issue in any way?

Comment: You can use a couple of DVI-D connectors to attach 2 displays, and the last one via DisplayPort or HDMI. For it you'll need an active adapter to DVI-D of course, but they are cheap.

Answer (score -1):

The two OS's listed will have no problems supporting multiple displays.

the real question is will this card support this set-up, in short no. At those resolutions you are going to be looking at at least two cards in crossfire and I still doubt the 270 will handle any kind of modern game at a total resolution of 7680x1140 even in crossfire due to its small amount of VRAM. If you're just using the system for web browsing you might just about get away with it

Comment: I don't plan on playing games on three monitors at all! Just general browsing and coding.

Comment: Crossfire is used in graphics intensive applications (read games). For the regular development it won't be utilized.

Comment: @TranslucentCloud I was just making it clear that for games it had no chance

Comment: The asker have clearly stated that he's not interested in gaming at all. Not sure why you have decided to bloat your answer with unnecessary data and terms. By the way, it has chance for a *modest* 3-display  gaming, R9 270X is pretty powerful.

Comment: @TranslucentCloud a simple google will provide enough evidence that gaming at 7680x1440 is not easily done, benchmarks have shown even running 3 very high end cards can only produce around 60fps one 270 has no chance

Comment: You are wrong. A simple [googling](http://us.hardware.info/reviews/4976/13/amd-radeon-r9-270-review-crysis-3---5760x1080-+-frametimes) reveals that at 5760x1080 in Crysis with medium settings R9 270X will produce a rather playable 30 FPS. A less performance hungry games, such as Diablo 3 will be definitely playable in 7680x1440.

Comment: @TranslucentCloud 5760x1080 is not the resolution the asker clearly states 7680x1440 any modern game you would have serious FPS issues with

Comment: Sure, you're completely right.